# Auto-generate ID when adding new document

Tags: php, database, uniqueidentifier, clusterpoint

My project use ClusterPoint database and I wonder if it's possible to insert document into the database with randomly assigned ID.

[This document seems to specify the "ID"](http://docs.clusterpoint.com/wiki/PHP_Modify) but what if it exists already? Is there a better way to generate unique identifiers.

Comment: why do you need random IDs? why not sequential IDs?

Comment: If not sequential ids, why not guids?

Comment: sequential id's can be troublesome in distributed databases, so I'm fine with any type of ID as long as it is guaranteed unique.

Comment: you could always generate a random id, do a fetch to the database to see if that id exists already, and if not insert it.

Comment: @JamesSpence this no longer makes insert operation atomic, as another record could be inserted while I'm checking, although the probability of that is ridiculously low. For now I'm performing insert anyway and if error is returned, re-generating ID and inserting again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve auto increment functionality by using separate doc for sequence and use transaction to increment it safely. Of course it might impact ingestion speed because each insert would require extra roundtrip for transaction to succeed.

```
try {          
          // Begin transaction
          $cpsSimple->beginTransaction();
          // Retrieve sequence document with id "sequence"
          $seq_doc = $cpsSimple->retrieveSingle("sequence", DOC_TYPE_ARRAY);
          //in sequence doc we store last id in field 'last_doc_id'
          $new_id = ++$seq_doc['last_doc_id'];
          $cpsSimple->updateSingle("sequence", $seq_doc);
          //commit
          $cpsSimple->commitTransaction();
          //add new document with allocated new id
          $doc = array('field1' => 'value1', 'field2' => 'value2');
          $cpsSimple->insertSingle($new_id, $doc);
    } catch (CPS_Exception $e) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved by attempting to re-insert the data if original operation fails. Here is my method in PHP:

```
function cpsInsert($cpsSimple, $data){
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++){
        try {
            $id = uniqid();
            $cpsSimple->insertSingle($id, $data);
            return $id;
        }catch(CPS_Exception $e){
            if($e->getCode() != 2626) throw $e;

            // will go for another attempt
        }
    }
    throw new Exception('Unable to generete unique ID');
}
```

I'm not sure if that's best approach, but it works.

Comment: I'm sure you designed this for a reason, but if you wanted to, instead of having a for loop, you could merely hook the catch to re-run the same function with the same data. Of course, I presume you did this so that it only attempts three times, after which it fails.

Comment: Yes, also no need to fill up call stack. I used to develop for 8086 in ASM and back then you would learn that function call is more expensive than for() loop.